# Yii2 + ajax not working

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I tried use answers about yii and ajax but not finded working examle.
My script in yii2 bacis views/site/about.php:

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/controllers/SiteController/sample' ?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                searchname: 10,
                searchby: 25,
                _csrf: '<?= Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken() ?>'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.search);
                console.log(data.code);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

My function in SiteController:

```
   public function actionSample() {

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

            $search = "some-string";
            $code = 20;
            \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return [
                'search' => $search,
                'code' => $code,
            ];
        }
    }
```

I see post  from ajax in browser OK.

```
 POST http://localhost/web/controllers/SiteController/sample    
    200 OK
```

But conroller not answer . I get: "undefined".
May be problems with url? But I tried other:
`Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/controllers/sample`. It didnt work too(

Comment: Please don't use offensive language, even in russian.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `/site/sample` instead or just `sample` if view belongs to action of `SiteController`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/site/sample',
    ...
});
```

Also placing JavaScript inside of `script` tag in view is not welcomed in Yii. You should use at least [registerJs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJs%28%29-detail) or [registerJsFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile%28%29-detail) or assets (recommended). There are dedicated sections about [assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html) and [client scripts](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html) in official guide.

Also make sure that your server configured to access `web/index.php` for correct work.

**Update:** We investigated problem deeper and the reason was the pretty urls were not enabled. Adding this to application config solved the problem:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
],
```

Comment: post with this URL - 200 OK too, but "data.code" is "undefined"

Comment: server configured from this manual : https://github.com/ilopX/yii2-basic-htaccess

Comment: @user3205692 Please check AJAX response, did it return expected JSON?

Comment: By the way server configurations are described in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html#add-extras-for-webserver), you can refer to it instead of third party manuals.

Comment: I suggest using browser tools instead or just `console.log(data)` without accessing `data.search` etc. just for testing purposes. What it contains?

Comment: I added  `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` and got in console next:  

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: When use `console.log(data)` without accessing I get in console all html index.php not about.php

Comment: url: '/site/sample', this indicate to the root directory.